# MVP architecture pattern example. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, mvp

I want to learn classic MVP architecture pattern and for this try to implement Weather app on Swift. I learned in theory how it should work but practically stuck on basic understanding. For now I have a model:

**Model**

```
class WeatherModel: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var main: Main?
}

class Main: Codable {
    var temperature: Float?
    var pressure: Int?
    var humidity: Int?
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temperature = "temp"
        case pressure
        case humidity
    }
```

**View**

```
final class WeatherViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var cityTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pressureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var humidityLabel: UILabel!

    private var presenter: WeatherPresenter!

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter = WeatherPresenter()
        cityTextField.delegate = self
        presenter.delegate = self

    }

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let city = cityTextField.text
        if let city = city {
            presenter.loadWeatherFor(city: city)
        }
    }
}

extension WeatherViewController: WeatherPresenterProtocol {

    // MARK: - WeatherPresenterProtocol

    func showWeather(data: WeatherModel) {
        if let temperature = data.main?.temperature {
            self.temperatureLabel.text = String(temperature)
        }
        if let pressure = data.main?.pressure {
            self.pressureLabel.text = Constants.pressure + String(pressure)
        }
        if let humidity = data.main?.humidity {
            self.humidityLabel.text = Constants.humidity + String(humidity)
        }
    }
}
```

**Presenter**

```
protocol WeatherPresenterProtocol: class {
    func showWeather(data: WeatherModel) // ?
}

final class WeatherPresenter {
    var model: WeatherModel!
    weak var delegate: WeatherPresenterProtocol?

    func loadWeatherFor(city: String) {
        Network.shared.getWeather(city) { [weak self] (weather, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.model = weather
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `Presenter` I receive data from a Network Service but I can't understand how to update `View` with this data (how to implement protocol in `Presenter`) because `View` shouldn't know about model but in my case it will know( Any idea to implement classic MVP will be appreciated!

And second question: how to implement protocol  in `Presenter` to get `Model` (as it is shown in the picture I've taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzTeyxIW_ow)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
func showWeather(data: WeatherModel)
```

to

```
func showWeather(temperature: String, pressure: String, humidity: String)
```

Move the construction of these strings from the View to the Presenter. This way, the View remains ignorant of the model.

The Presenter should not speak directly to the full View, only to the protocol.

Comment: yeah, I thought about that way, but for this example I chose 3 fields. Actually I parse the whole OpenWeatherMap API with more than 10 arguments and as a result it will not be "swifty" (

Comment: You can either a) package those 10 arguments into a simple struct. This is not the Model. It's a Request Model. Or you can b) call 10 different protocol methods, like `showTemperature`, etc. Either way, pass strings, not original Model data.

Comment: @JonReid what do you meant by `Presenter should not speak directly to the full View`? Is that means View should not conform the presenter's `WeatherPresenterProtocol`?

Comment: @YoonLee You have it right in your code: the WeatherPresenter has a reference to a delegate that is the protocol only, not the whole view controller.

Comment: @JonReid Thank you. How about the presenter? Do presenter needs to have a protocol that view can access to its and request data interaction to presenter?

Comment: No. The view controller should talk directly to the Presenter. The Presenter talks back indirectly, through a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, in the MVP the presenter will take care of updating the view, so modify your presenter to have the view property. Here the view holds nothing but the WeatherController instance.

In terms of the MVP, the UIViewController subclasses are in fact the Views and not the Presenters.

```
    class WeatherPresenter : WeatherViewPresenter {
         unowned let view: WeatherView
         let weather: WeatherModel

         required init(view: WeatherView, weather: WeatherModel) {
            self.view = view
            self.weather = weather
         }

        func updateWeatherView() {
           //...update properties on your weather view
           self.view.setTemperature(self.weather.temperature)
        }
    }
```

For example,To update the temperature label, have a protocol to set the temperature value. You can have multiple methods to set multiple properties or have one for all of your UI elements in weather view.

```
protocol WeatherView: class {
    func setTemperature(temp: String)
    //same for pressure, humid etc
}
```

Now write a  protocol for weather presenter

```
protocol WeatherViewPresenter {
    init(view: WeatherView, weather: WeatherModel)
    func updateWeatherView()
}
```

Now that you have the presenter setup for weather class, you would use it like

```
class WeatherViewController : UIViewController, WeatherView {
    var presenter: WeatherViewPresenter!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          let model = //your weather model
          presenter = WeatherPresenter(view: self, weather: model)
    }

    func setTemperature(temp: String) {
        self.temperatureLabel.text = temp
    }

}
```

After you get the data from weather, just call  `self.presenter.updateWeatherView()` to update the weather view.

For more detailed info, please [refer](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52)

Comment: thanks for answer, but one question still remains: our `View` (i.e. WeatherViewController) will know about `Model`, right? Because I thought that we shouldn't know anything about `Model`, just update UI on the `View`

Comment: @Vlad No,Not if you initiate the model through the presenter. Either you can move all your api calls to presenter, which you already did. By that way, your view will only know about presenter.

Comment: I prefer the protocol solution discussed above over having a reference to the view in the presenter. Simply because protocol solution decouples the presenter from the view.